# I can't "smart UV Project"

Tags: uv, edit-mode, texture-painting

I'm a noob in Blender, and I was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJaF7NBJudk). Around 1:27, he used Ctrl + Numpad, and from that point onward, I couldn't enter edit mode in that area. This is problematic because now I want to texture paint my object, but I can't paint the area where I used Ctrl + Numpad.
I attempted to resolve this issue, and now I can visualize that area in edit mode. However, only the points are visible, and there are no faces between them (refer to the picture for more details).

Could someone please help me?[image: Hammer edit mode]

Comment: If you slow the tutorial right down, he's using Ctrl-Numpad + (plus) which extends the selection one loop to the right and then 'H' to hide the selected section. That's so that he can add a loop cut round the remaining part and move it up to square off the upper corners of the hammer head. I've not looked at the rest of the video, but to unhide that section use Alt-H (in Edit mode).

Comment: I'm sorry but the title seems completely unrelated to the question. I mean of course, if you cannot see and select the faces you cannot unwrap them... but you mention unwrapping nowhere else, just painting. Anyway, I agree with @JohnEason - the selected mesh gets hidden with `H`, unfortunately it is not shown how to unhide it again with `Alt`+`H`. To be honest, I don't think those very quick timelapse videos without any explanations are not very suitable for beginners when you don't even know yet how to hide and unhide parts of the mesh. I would do more beginner tutorials at first.

Comment: This didn't work, that was the first thing I tried but nothing changed. I just recreated the object in a different way. Sorry for the badly chosen title. Thank you very much for your help.